# Django: How to access original (unmodified) instance in post_save signal

Tags: python, django, postgresql, denormalization, django-signals

I want to do a data denormalization for better performance, and put a sum of votes my blog post receives inside Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """ Blog entry """
    author          = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text            = models.TextField()
    rating          = models.IntegerField(default=0) # here is the sum of votes!

class Vote(models.Model):
    """ Vote for blog entry """
    post            = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    voter           = models.ForeignKey(User)
    value           = models.IntegerField()
```

Ofcourse, I need to keep `Post.rating` value actual. Nornally I would use database triggers for that, but now I've decided to make a `post_save` signal (to reduce database process time):

```
# vote was saved
@receiver(post_save, sender=Vote)
def update_post_votes(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """ Update post rating """
    if created:
        instance.post.rating += instance.value
        instance.post.save()
    else:
        # if vote was updated, we need to remove the old vote value and add the new one
        # but how...?
```

How can I access the instance value before it was saved? In database triggers, i would have `OLD` and `NEW` predefines for this, but is there something like this in post_save signals?

**UPDATE**

The solution based on Mark's the answer:

```
# vote was saved
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Vote)
def update_post_votes_on_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """ Update post rating """
    # if vote is being updated, then we must remove previous value first
    if instance.id:
        old_vote = Vote.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
        instance.post.rating -= old_vote.value
    # now adding the new vote
    instance.post.rating += instance.value
    instance.post.save()
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I believe `post_save` is too late to retrieve the unmodified version. As the name implies the data has already been written to the db at that point. You should use `pre_save` instead. In that case you can retrieve the model from the db via pk: `old = Vote.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)` and check for differences in the current instance and the previous instance.

Answer (score 24):

This is **not an** optimal solution, but it works.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=SomeModel)
def model_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance._pre_save_instance = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except SomeModel.DoesNotExist:
        instance._pre_save_instance = instance


@receiver(signal=post_save, sender=SomeModel)
def model_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    pre_save_instance = instance._pre_save_instance
    post_save_instance = instance
```

Comment: Why it is not optimal?

Comment: @CharanjitSingh It works, but I'm not sure this is the exact right way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, As Far As I believe, it might be optimal, but less predictive, as the old instance could be deleted from the memory, I am not sure about the signals workflow of django, but that could be an issue.

Comment: I would only suggest that instead of saving the whole instance, just store the subset of data that you need for comparison in the post_save.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FieldTracker from django-model-utils: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker