# Django - Pass value from pre_save to post_save methods on model

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django model like so...

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

I'm trying to compare two values - the `title` field before the user changes it, and the `title` after. I don't want to save both values in the database at one time (only need one `title` field), so I'd like to use `pre_save` and `post_save` methods to do this. Is it possible to get the title before the save, then hold this value to be passed into the `post_save` method?

The pre_save and post_save methods look like so...

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Example, uid='...')
def compare_title_changes(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # get the current title name here
    x = instance.title

@receiver(post_save, sender=Example, uid='...')
def compare_title_changes(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # get the new title name here and compare the difference
    x = instance.title # <- new title
    if x == old_title_name: # <- this is currently undefined, but should be retrieved from the pre_save method somehow
        ...do some logic here...
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

As was pointed out to me, pre_save and post_save both occur after save() is called. What I was looking for is something like pre_save() but before the actual save method is called. I set this on the model so that the logic to be performed will be accessible wherever the instance is saved from (either admin or from a user view)

Comment: You might be looking at the wrong direction. `pre_save` is called AFTER the user changes the value (somewhere in your code `example.save()`, such as [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields)) and BEFORE the data reach the database.

Comment: What is the reason that the logic in the post_save callback isn't done in the pre_save callback?

Comment: @gdlmx I see, my mistake! Thanks very much. I'll edit my question to reflect this - how might I achieve this effect at the models.py level? I set it at the model level since I want the logic to be available whenever the model is saved (either in the admin, or a user view, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Example.objects.get(pk=instance.id)` to get the old title from the database in the `pre_save` handler function:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Example, uid='...')
def compare_title_changes(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    new_title = instance.title  # this is the updated value
    old_title = Example.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
    # Compare the old and new titles here ...
```

This trick was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582410/django-how-to-access-original-unmodified-instance-in-post-save-signal) a long time ago. I've not tested it with the recent Django version. Please let me know whether it's still working.

Answer (score 1):

We can only say object has changed if "save" method passes successfully, so `post_save` is good to be sure that model object has updated.

Setting on the fly attribute on model class instance can do the task, as the same instance is passed from pre_save to post_save.

```
def set_flag_on_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # Check here if flag setting condition satisfies
    set_the_flag = true
    if set_the_flag:  
      instance.my_flag=0


def check_flag_on_post_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
   try:
      print(instance.my_flag)
      print('Flag set') 
   except AttributeError:
      print('Flag not set')


pre_save.connect(set_flag_on_pre_save, sender=ModelClass)

post_save.connect(check_flag_on_post_save, sender=ModelClass)
```